# SharePoint with MS Dynamics CRM 365 online: FIELD LEVEL DOCUMENT UPLOAD by custom code

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-services, file-upload, share, dynamics-crm

I have an entity like "Share" it is already integrated with SharePoint from CRM online 365, in that share entity I have around 50 fields, apart from those 50 fields.

I want to integrate the documents in SharePoint for specified fields only, like 10 fields out of 50, I want to achieve this functionality by using custom code (PLUGIN).

Can anyone suggest me some solution?